# Extension 'Live Share' cannot format file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was pair programming with a coworker using VS Code Live Share that he started. I hit my usual format hotkey and was prompted to choose "fix" my formatter and given the option to use the Live Share formatter (which I assumed was the one that my coworker was using or that it was running it through his computer via the Live Share server).

Anyways, now I'm back just programming like normal (not in a Live Share) but when I hit the format hotkey it no longer works and I see the following message:

Extension 'Live Share' cannot format ..... :

[image: live share not able to format message]

Can someone help me get back to my normal formatter. I looked in settings but haven't seen how to do that yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Figured it out!

Open the command palette

Go to Format Document With...

[image: format doc with]

Configure Default Formatter
[image: configure default formatter]

And reselect your preferred formatter:

[image: select your formatter of choice]